# Visual Studio 2012 - Command Recognition

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

```
Public Class HomeController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Function Index() As ActionResult

    End Function
End Class
```

The command parts "System.Web.Mvc.Controller" and "ActionResult" are not recognized.

The highlighter does also not highlight them.

The DLL and XML files "System.Web.Mvc" are in the bin folder of the project placed.

Comment: In Visual Studio solution explorer, check the references section. I guess, System.Web.Mvc.dll is not referenced or it has some version issue. Add the reference of the correct version of dll to your project

Comment: The references are set.

I am getting the error message that those mentioned command parts are not "defined", and "ViewData()" for example is stated as "not declared" in the error messages. 

In the template project "MVC4 Internet Application" it does work.

Comment: To clarify the above, it does not work in a new empty project.